# How to mutate a new column in dataframe ifelse date is between 2 dates in another column?

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe with some dates, and I have another dataframe with some dates of weather events.
I want to mutate a column onto original dataframe, if any of the dates are between the weather event dates in the second dataframe, paste the name of the Event, otherwise output a 'N'.

However I'm getting the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
Problem while computing `Event = ifelse(...)`.
x `Event` must be size 1, not 17.
i Did you mean: `Event = list(ifelse(...))` ?
i The error occurred in row 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My Code:

```
    data.frame(Events)
                          Name  StartDate    EndDate Flood_Storm_EventFlag EscapeofWater_EventFlag
1                       2007-6 2007-06-13 2007-07-02                     Y                       N
2                       2007-7 2007-07-20 2007-07-27                     Y                       N
3         February 2014 Storms 2014-02-03 2014-02-17                     Y                       N
4                      Desmond 2015-12-04 2015-12-07                     Y                       N
5                          Eva 2015-12-25 2015-12-28                     Y                       N
6                        Frank 2015-12-29 2016-01-08                     Y                       N
7                        Ciara 2020-02-08 2020-02-12                     Y                       N
8                       Dennis 2020-02-15 2020-02-28                     Y                       N
9     2021009A (July Floods 1) 2021-07-12 2021-07-19                     Y                       N
10             (July Floods 2) 2021-07-24 2021-08-02                     Y                       N
11 Dudley, Eunice and Franklin 2022-02-16 2022-02-28                     Y                       N
12                      2009-1 2009-01-02 2009-01-11                     N                       Y
13                     2009-12 2009-12-27 2010-01-19                     N                       Y
14                     2010-11 2010-11-28 2010-12-12                     N                       Y
15                     2010-12 2010-12-19 2011-01-08                     N                       Y
16                      2018-2 2018-02-28 2018-03-08                     N                       Y
17                     2022-12 2022-12-08 2022-12-18                     N                       Y


dates <- c("2007-06-13", "2007-05-13", "2007-06-14", "2009-01-04", "2009-01-15")
AccidentDate <- as.Date(dates)
PolicyType <- c("Home", "Home", "Motor", "Home", "Home")

df <- data.frame(AccidentDate, PolicyType)

x <- df %>%
mutate(Event = ifelse(AccidentDate >= Events$StartDate & AccidentDate <= Events$EndDate & PolicyType == "Home", Events$Name, 'N'))
```

I'm not exactly sure why cannot I create a new column this way. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you're getting multiple matches **both ways**. You could:

- Use `any()` to get a single logical value instead of one per row in `Events`.
- Use `.by` (or `group_by` in `dplyr` < 1.1.0) to pass only one `AccidentDate` at a time when you extract the name.

```
library(dplyr)

# dplyr >= 1.1.0

df |>
  mutate(Event = ifelse(any(AccidentDate >= Events$StartDate & AccidentDate <= Events$EndDate) & PolicyType == "Home",
                        Events$Name[AccidentDate >= Events$StartDate & AccidentDate <= Events$EndDate],
                        "N"), 
         .by = "AccidentDate")

# dplyr < 1.1.0 (Update 3/3-2022)

df |>
  group_by(AccidentDate) |>
  mutate(Event = ifelse(any(AccidentDate >= Events$StartDate & AccidentDate <= Events$EndDate) & PolicyType == "Home",
                        Events$Name[AccidentDate >= Events$StartDate & AccidentDate <= Events$EndDate],
                        "N")) |>
  ungroup()
```

I've assumed that there can only be a single match. You might want to check this.

**Output:**

```
  AccidentDate PolicyType  Event
1   2007-06-13       Home 2007-6
2   2007-05-13       Home      N
3   2007-06-14      Motor      N
4   2009-01-04       Home      N
5   2009-01-15       Home      N
```

---

**Update:** You could also consider a join:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  left_join(Events |> select(Event = Name, StartDate, EndDate),
            join_by(between(AccidentDate, StartDate, EndDate))) |>
  select(AccidentDate, PolicyType, Event) |>
  mutate(Event = ifelse(PolicyType == "Home", Event, NA))
```

To use `between`, instead of `join_by(AccidentDate >= StartDate, AccidentDate <= EndDate`) it all need to be `date`-types:

```
Events <- mutate(Events, across(StartDate:EndDate, as.Date))
```

Comment: For a learning point of view, can you quickly explain why I'm grouping by Accident Date? does this make the code go row by row through the dataframe?

Comment: And lets say i have two rows with same accident date - will this cause issues?

Comment: Exactly. If you can have this situation substitute `group_by(AccidentDate)` with `rowwise()`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This was very helpful, I've been struggling with this for days -I really appreciate it!